# Problem in taking input while running a c++ program

Tags: c++, string, stack

Hey I was solving a stack problem and i have written my logic for it but when i run my program .
And providing 3 as input.​

```
(a+(b*c))+(d/e)​
((())(()))
((((()
```

It is not taking input correctly .At the end of the 3 there is question mark symbol appearing .
[image: window while running my code]

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<stack> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    
    long int t;
    cin>>t;
    
    while(t--){
        stack< pair<char,int> > stk1;
        string s;
        cin>>s;
//       getline(cin, s);

        vector<int> vect;
        int i=0,k=1,l=1;
        
        while(s[i] != '\0' ){
            if(s[i]=='('){
                stk1.push( {'(' , k}  );
                vect.push_back(k);
                k++;
            }
            else if( s[i]== ')'){
                if(stk1.empty()){
                    vect.push_back(l);
                    l++;
                }else{
                    vect.push_back( stk1.top().second);
                    stk1.pop();
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        for(int z=0;z<vect.size();z++){
            cout<<vect[z]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: why you are providing `while(i--)` it should be like `while(i=lastLimit)`

Comment: @Analyst A few things wrong with `while(i=lastLimit)`, plus I'm not drawing a connection between your comment and the question so I can't validate the logic of what I think you meant to write.

Comment: In such a small, simple program, you ought to be able to quickly find the problem by stepping through with a debugger or using other debugging techniques to examine the actual program state and compare it with what you expect.

Comment: @paddy I know how to debug the code but i was not able to find the error . I had done many ques but this is my first time getting this problem.

Comment: @Analyst i have written ``` while(t--)``` that means it will run t times . It is same as writting the last limit .

Comment: @TUSHARYADAV i think you should declare an `int t=lastLimit` as `t--` means decrementing the value of `t`

Answer (score 0):

I was using DEV C++ in that only this error was comming not in code blocks .
so there was saome problem in dev c++ only.